# Android- How do i get the URI of the latest file saved by the system?

Tags: android, image, uri, mediastore

In android, how could I get the URI last file saved to the system? I need this ability for an image editting application. As far as I can tell ContentObserver can only check if something has changed and neither MediaStore.Images.Media or MediaStore.Files have a method I could use. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate trough the files in the folder(s) your application is targeting and get the newest file trough the `lastModified()` method then you could get it's location with the `getPath()` method.

```
public File getNewestFileInDirectory() {
   File newestFile = null;

   // start loop trough files in directory
   File file = new File(filePath);
   if (newestFile == null || file.lastModified().after(newestFile.lastModified())) {
      newestFile = file;
   }
   // end loop trough files in directory

   return newestFile;
}
```

Comment: How would I get all the file paths from a directory?

Comment: Google "loop all files in directory java" and then simply call file.getPath() on each file ...