# How can I get the file name/uri of the last taken photo?

Tags: java, android, upload, camera, android-gallery

I definitely need some help on this one! My problem is that I can't find out how to get the Uri of the last taken photo. I can upload a photo when I choose it from the gallery, but the other feature is missing. The camera starts and after the photo is taken it is saved in the gallery, but somehow I can't find out the URI of the last taken photo. Please help!

Regards,

Habib

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final int SELECT_FILE = 1;
    private final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;
    private ImageView ivImage;
    private Button btnSetImage;
    TextView tv;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        btnSetImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        btnSetImage.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    }

    private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    };

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
        String upLoadServerUri = "...upload.php";
        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
            return 0;
        }
        try { // open a URL connection to the Server
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP
                                                                // connection to
                                                                // the URL
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of
                                                            // maximum size

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage
                    + ": " + serverResponseCode);
            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText("File Upload Completed.");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                    "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }

    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                            SELECT_FILE);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bm;
                    BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            btmapOptions);

                    // bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 70, 70, true);
                    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream fOut = null;
                    final File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System
                            .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                    try {
                        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                        fOut.flush();
                        fOut.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                final String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri,
                        MainActivity.this);
                Bitmap bm;
                BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);
                ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                        "Uploading file...", true);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                tv.setText("uploading started.....");
                            }
                        });

                        int response = uploadFile(tempPath);
                        System.out.println("RES : " + response);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = activity
                .managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this could be a duplicate see this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238846/android-how-do-i-get-the-uri-of-the-latest-file-saved-by-the-system

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as the path/file where camera stores the photo instead of looking for latest photo.

`Uri.fromFile(f)`

Camera intent stores the image to the location which you pass it. So may be store the path of the image a global in the activity since it's a temp path that you are passing. And use it the on activity result method to access the file.